# Как исправить проблему игнорирования Patternом первого совпадения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть функция, которая заменяет значение в {}, но она игнорирует первое совпадение. Т.е. В строке "{a} {b} {c}" она находит и заменяет всё кроме "{a}".

Паттерн:

```
\{(\w+)}
```

Код функции:

```java
public static String replaceEmoji(@Nullable String string) {
        if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) return string;
 
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w+)}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(string);
 
        if (!m.find()) return string;
 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(
                    sb,
                    Emojis.getEmoji(m.group(1))
            );
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
 
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: [Вроде, работает, как надо](https://regex101.com/r/POsYY8/1), покажите ваш код.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [код функции](https://pastebin.com/Tp7zY57y)

Comment: Ошибка в проверке на совпадение, строка `if (!m.find()) return string;`  лишняя. Удалить следует и `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо большое. Можете ответить на вопрос, чтобы я отметил данное решение как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Основная ошибка в проверке на совпадение, строка `if (!m.find()) return string;` лишняя.
2. Удалите `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE`, в вашем шаблоне нет ни букв, ни "якорей" `^` и `$`.

```java
public static String replaceEmoji(@Nullable String string) {
    if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) return string;
 
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w+)}").matcher(string);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(
                sb,
                Emojis.getEmoji(m.group(1))
        );
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

См. [пример работы кода на Java](https://ideone.com/dqLi6e).